# Resizing existing mediawiki images

Tags: linux, mediawiki, image-resizing

I´ve got an older mediawiki installation (v1.21) with a lot of images. But the images wasn´t resized before uploading so the images are really big. How could I resize all linked images in mediawiki so the file size are smaller but all the links are working?

And: Is there an option to set up that all future uploaded files are automatically resized to maximum dimension?

Answer (score 0):

Use [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/mogrify.php):

```
mogrify -resize 256x256 *.jpg
```

Comment: You mean that I only have to resize the images? No changing in mediawiki needed? If it will be I have to write a one-liner that will go through all image folders and resize they.

Comment: Are any recognition for that a image is in portrait or landscape orientation? I want to set up max. pixel for height and width - depending on the orientation the images should converted to the right max. pixel.

Comment: Mediawiki display all images in their size, unless you specify Resizing option. https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Images#Size_and_frame

Comment: Well, it works but now the metadata in mediawiki are inaccurate - how could I make them consistent?

Comment: I'm guessing you didn't get anywhere with this?